# Issues calling a method with user input

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program in which the first step is for the user to input their name (in the User class). I wanted to create a method (in another class) that specifically reads the input and then implement that method in my User class.

However, I'm getting a NullPointerException error and I don't quite understand why.

```
 public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         User newUser=new User();
         newUser.CreateName(); 
     }
 }
 public class User {
     UserInput ui;
     public void CreateName(){
         System.out.println("Enter your name:");
         String name= ui.Input();
     }
 }
 public class UserInput {
     public String Input(){
         Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
         String s=input.nextLine();
         return s;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share your stacktrace

Comment: You have not initialized ui

Comment: In `User` `ui` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The instance of UserInput is not initialized, it has null value.

Try changing in **User class**:

```
UserInput ui;
```

to

```
UserInput ui = new UserInput();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate `User` class in your `main` method, all the global instance attributes (In your case `UserInput ui`) of `User` class gets loaded into the memory, with its default values, and hence it is derived data type automatically its default value will be set to `null`.

Now you are calling a method on that reference which is `null`, calling any method on a null reference causes `NullPointerException`. So you need to initialize your `UserInput` reference to an object.

Either while declaring your attribute `UserInput ui = new UserInput();`, so this object is getting a global scope within your `User` class, and can be accessed across the current class and also in the other classes in same package.

Or you can initialize that attribute inside your `CreateName()` method like

```
public void CreateName(){
    System.out.println("Enter your name:");
    ui = new UserInput();
    String name= ui.Input();
}
```

So that object becomes local to the method, and hence you are not passing its reference to any other method, it will be garbage collected before the method execution finishes.